# Where should magic methods be placed inside a class relative to other methods?

Tags: python

When I implement magic/special methods inside a class (`__len__`, `__contains__`, `__iter__`), are they usually placed above other methods I implement (right after `__init__`) or below? Also, is there an order that these magic methods are typically placed in? Alphabetically or...?

Answer (score 0):

There is no predefined style, so you should follow the standards of the project/team you're working in.

A good idea is to group them logically, in the way that makes your code intent easier to understand.

That said, this question is mostly opinion based and offtopic here, so I'm voting to close it.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not covered in a PEP document, there's no community "standard".
These decisions are something to work out with whomever will be reading and maintaining your code.

In my most recent project, we arrange them in order of incremental development: put the house-keeping methods (e.g. `__init__`) first, then those useful for debugging (e.g. `__repr__`), then the basic comparators (`__lt__`, `__contains__`), iteration support, continuing in order of type-specificity.